# Rotation problem

Tags: transforms

I have a problem with Rotation, is it possible to reset the rotation of a mesh (see photo).

I downloaded the file and am disassembling it and now I see that the rotation values are very strange.

Is it possible to reset the rotation to match what I actually see ?

[image]

Comment: Could you try Ctrl+A (for apply) and then select Apply Rotation?

Comment: By "what I see", do you mean the "world" rotation? If so, do what @Jummit suggests, CTRL-A and select Apply Rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the rotation to 0,0,0 while keeping the mesh orientation, apply the rotation by hitting Ctr+A and selecting `Rotation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the rotation of the mesh but zero the rotation of the object, I suggest you copy the value of an axis (X, Y or Z), apply that amount of rotation in Edit Mode (R, [the letter of the axis], Ctrl+V), then clear the value in Object View. Repeat with all three axes.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about.
That's fantastic, I've been working on this for quite some time now.
Thank you very much !